Linear regression in R, but objective is the sum of a group
My objective is to run a linear regression model with no intercepts, but my data is grouped in the target variable.
My data frame has: id_1, id_2, input_number and target. any combination of id_1 and id_2 is unique and has an associated input number. However, target is the same for every id_1.
I want to find a factor for each id_2 such that the sum of the product of "factor" and "input_number" over each id_1 approximates the target, and I have no real understanding of where to start.
Edit: I added some tables for an example
input_df



id_1
id_2
input_number
target




1
a
5
50


1
b
10
50


2
a
5
15


3
b
5
20



output_df (just illustrative)



id_2
factor




a
4


b
3



input_df %>% 
inner_join (output_df , by = c("id_2"))  %>% 
mutate (prediction = factor * input_number) %>% 
group_by (id_1, target) %>%
summarise (prediction = sum (prediction))




id_1
prediction
target




1
50
50


2
20
15


3
15
20




the statement reads: want to find a coefficient ... SUCH THAT the sum .. ...it seems incomplete

Thank you @Onyambu, I added an example and extra context, although I am not sure how useful it will be.

Actually, I think my input format may be acting as a roadblock. I could use a sparse matrix with rows id_1, columns id_2, values input_number, and then the objective is just "target"

Now that you have the code and everything, this seems to be a stackoverflow question and not a cross validated question. Should be migrated back to stackoverflow

Note that if there exists randomness then you can use nls model, otherwise optim:
f <- function(par, x, y, z)ave(x* par[factor(z)], y, FUN = sum)
(mod <- nls(target~f(c(a,b), input_number, id_1, id_2), df, c(a=1, b=1)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: target ~ f(c(a, b), input_number, id_1, id_2)
   data: df
    a     b 
2.818 3.636 
 residual sum-of-squares: 4.545

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.263e-09

cbind(df, pred = predict(mod, df))

  id_1 id_2 input_number target     pred
1    1    a            5     50 50.45455
2    1    b           10     50 50.45455
3    2    a            5     15 14.09091
4    3    b            5     20 18.18182


Using optim:
g <- \(x)crossprod(with(df, f(x, input_number, id_1, id_2) - target))
(mod1 <- optim(c(1,1), g, control = list(reltol = 1e-15)))

$par
[1] 2.818182 3.636364

$value
[1] 4.545455

$counts
function gradient 
     115       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
cbind(df, pred = mod1$par[factor(df$id_2)]*df$input_number) 
  id_1 id_2 input_number target     pred
1    1    a            5     50 14.09091
2    1    b           10     50 36.36364
3    2    a            5     15 14.09091
4    3    b            5     20 18.18182


The randomness is caused by id_2 == 3 and 4. If we switch the two, we can only use optim:
df[3:4,4] <- c(20, 15)
c(mod1 <- optim(c(1,1), g, control = list(reltol = 1e-15)))
$par
[1] 4 3

$value
[1] 4.583464e-12

$counts
function gradient 
     129       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

cbind(df, pred = mod1$par[factor(df$id_2)]*df$input_number) 
  id_1 id_2 input_number target pred
1    1    a            5     50   20
2    1    b           10     50   30
3    2    a            5     20   20
4    3    b            5     15   15


Thank you so much! I think I understand the code, but just checking, if instead of just a and b as options for id_2 we have arbitrarily many values, do we need to initilize every one of them?

@Neoleogeo No. I was doing so to make it easier. You can just use par. eg nls(target~f(par, input_number, id_1, id_2), df, start=list( par = c(1, 1)))
